# How to use SQL Query to get values from database using <= operator?

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable, dataset

I have the following query :

```
 "C_START>= '01/01/0001 06:00:00 PM' AND C_END <= '01/01/0001 08:00:00 PM'"
```

Where `C_START` and `C_END` are the column names of the `DataTable`.

Now I'm passing this query as:

```
public static DataTable getval(query, dt)
{
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
    myTable = dt.Clone();
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select(query);
    if (dr.Length > 0)
    {
       foreach (DataRow r in dr)
       {
          myTable.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
       }
    }
    return myTable;
}
```

ON displaying this `myTable` in my `GridView`, I can see the list of all records for which C_START is greater than or equal to 6 PM. There is something wrong in C_END. It shows all records including those whose C_END value is greater than 8 PM which is wrong as per the query passed. Please suggest how to eliminate this issue.

Comment: What is `expr`?  As is this code will not compile as you are declaring `DataRow[] dr` twice.  Once with `query` and once with `expr`.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code block. You can review now. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: You still have two `DataRow[] dr` declarations and still have not told me what is in `expr`.

Comment: Hey Evan, Check out now. Sorry for the edit crap

Comment: There used to be an issue with `DataTable.Select` and multiple conditions back in older .Net versions.  Can you try `"C_START>= '01/01/0001 06:00:00 PM' AND (C_END <= '01/01/0001 08:00:00 PM')"`?  For some reason the parentheses seem to help it out.

Comment: @EvanL: I tried, its not working, getting the same results.

Comment: I added an answer.  If that does not work, can you please post your calling code?  And the code you use to bind the table to your grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ instead of `DataTable.Select()` to get better results I believe.  Instead of passing a query to the Method, pass it your start/end `DateTime` and use those for the conditions.  Of course you could pass it strings, but you would need to do some conversion.

The below example is assuming your `C_START` and `C_END` values are of type `DateTime` in the `DataTable`.

```
    //Add more parameters based on your conditions
    public static DataTable GetVal(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DataTable dt)
    {
        using (var myTable = dt.Clone())
        {
            var dr = from row in myTable.AsEnumerable()
                where row.Field<DateTime>("C_START") >= startDate
                   && row.Field<DateTime>("C_END") <= endDate
                   //Add more && statements to complete the query as needed.
                   //A string query is OK but you are prone to mistakes, why not let the compiler do the work.
                select new {row};

            foreach (var row in dr)
            {
                myTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return myTable;
        }
     }
```

Also you should consider more descriptive method names than things like `GetVal`.  This method returns a `DataTable` not a value, so I would do something like `GetFilteredDataSet` or `FilterDataTableByDate`.  And method names in C# are in Camel Case not lowercase.

Comment: Evan, I have some other conditions added as well in my actual solution. So, its not only the start time and end time, there are other conditions in the actual query containing string as well. Though your answer is right, but in my case it won't prove that much helpful as I need to run this whole query all at once. And I have taken care of the method names. For showing here, I used those names. The names are different in actual code.

Comment: You can easily make this method take more conditons, though I would think if you have that many filter conditions you might just want to query the database a bit more succinctly.  You won't escape verbosity with a ton of filter conditions, so you might as well just expand this method to take all conditional material.  Or create overloads of the same method to take different filter parameters if the conditions change at run time.

Comment: Calling code: 
'if (query != string.Empty)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = genericMethods.createTable(query,dsjob);
   dsjob = new DataSet();
   dsjob.Tables.Add(dt);
}
BindGrid();'

Comment: I debugged the code, and I found out the datatable that is returned from the method getval() is itself having inappropriate values (values that you could normally get on running select without any of the conditions that I've used). So, the data being fetched is itself not coming correctly from the cloned table.

Comment: Well that's a different question then I suppose.  Still I would advocate using LINQ queries in place of `DataTable.Select()` any day.

Comment: I wish I could use it. If try changing the structure now, a hell lot of changes are needed and I don't wanna work overnights! ;)

Comment: Lol okay then ;)  Sorry to waste your time